# Why am I being limited to ten posts on a custom loop?

Tags: loop

For example, I have a link on my site like /tag/green and select content from all posts tagged green are shown using a file loop-tag.php which is about as simple as

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
<!-- Here I grab the image from the post with that tag -->  
<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

This works however it is being limited to 10 posts.  Why is this being limited to 10 like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because it must be set in back end of your wordpress site.
You can check and change it from `Blog pages show at most` field from settings => Reading pages menu. As shown in below screenshot.

[image: Blog pages show at most]

It will change the setting for all pages , but if you want to make this change only for tag page then in your case you can change the code in loop-tag.php file as following :

```
global $wp;
$s_array = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );  // Change to how many posts you want to display 
$new_query = array_merge( $s_array, (array) $wp->query_vars );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $new_query );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
         ?>
        <!-- Here I grab the image from the post with that tag --> 
        <?php
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

You can also use [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook to change post limit.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation!  I do want to make this independent of admin settings so that custom query is perfect.

Comment: @vinod_dalvi Can you update your post to use `new WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()` which is not recommended.  Also @Zac, if you want to adjust the number of posts only on a particular template, you should use the `pre_get_posts` filter, so you do not run the query twice.